# Rails - showing grouped records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, unique

I have some records:

```
Type Name
2 USA
2 USA
3 Canada
4 Mexico 
1 Canada
2 Mexico
3 USA
```

I just want to show the list of unique types: 1,2,3,4 (no double, triple records).
I was trying to do something like that in my view:

```
<% @Orders.group(:type).each do |order| %>
... showing in the table
<% end %>
```

But I got following error:
undefined method `group' for #

Do I need to add some method in the controller/model? 
Why - if .each method works ok in the view, group doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what exactly you are trying to return/display, but I think you might want to look at `#group_by` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

Alternatively, look at some of the aggregate methods on this page: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-calculate

Answer (score 0):

Usually an instance variable is lowercase, that is `@orders` not `@Orders`.  The error is telling you that it cannot find a method `group` for whatever it is that's in `@Orders`, so that's what you would focus on.

Once that's sorted out, you may want to use either the ActiveRecord `distinct` operator, or, if your records are in ruby, use `.uniq` on a collection (i.e. array).